# How can I get the current pagid within the backoffice & frontend?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

So the below code works perfectly fine for the front-end however always returns null/0 in the back-office when rendered within the grid.

This code is within a custom grid editor.

```
int pageid = Convert.ToInt32(UmbracoContext.Current.PageId);
```

How can I make it work from backoffice to?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone needs the answer I used the following:

```
var currentcontent = Lecoati.LeBlender.Extension.Helper.GetCurrentContent();
```

Answer was found on an Umbraco forum post which you can find [here](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/leblender/general-discussion/64907-How-do-I-see-the-CurrentPage-value).